# Limit of Improper integral from "0 to 0"

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have a problem which I think i'm close to solve, but I got stuck. 
The problem is as follows:
Let f be continuous on [0,1] and let [image]
. Show that the following limit exists and find it:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}dx$$
My attempt was as follows:
by the fundamental theorem of calculus, because f(x)/x is continuous on (0,1],
there's a function G(x) such that for all x in (0,1] G'(x)=f(x)/x
so 
[image]
      I don't have any ideas how to get further from here.
after checking for some private cases, my guess is that the limit is
f(0)*ln(b/a).
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: @Tamr I tried to replace your image with LaTeX, but I may have deleted the first one by accident. Sorry. Can you put it back? And to be honest, you should probably LaTeX-ize the rest of your math if you want to get more answers.

Comment: Alright, working on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $$\int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon} \frac{f(0)}{x} dx = f(0) (\log(b\varepsilon)-\log(a\varepsilon)) = f(0) \log(b/a).$$
Since $f$ is continuous, for any $\varepsilon'>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon'$ for all $|x| \le \delta$. Thus forall $0 <\epsilon <\delta/b$ we have
$$\left| \int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx - f(0) \log(b/a)  \right| \leq \int_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon} \frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{x} dx \le \varepsilon' \log(b/a).$$
This proves that the limes is $f(0) \log(b/a)$.

Note that the limes is related to "prinicpal values", see [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).